# How to destructure an object and update MySQL with keys and values?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, destructuring

I am passing data from a react frontend to an express backend:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/api', {foo: true, bar: false});
```

In the backend I am updating a MySQL database like

```
app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  const {foo, bar} = req.body;
  const sql = `UPDATE users SET foo = ?, bar = ?`;
  connection.query(sql, [foo, bar], (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({err: err});
    } else {
      res.send({updated: true});
    }
  })
});
```

What if I don't know the keys of the data I'm passing? Like foo and bar could be whatever.

I need to know the keys that I am currently destructuring in `const {foo, bar} = req.body`.
Additionally I need to have them in the column part of the UPDATE string in `foo = ?` and `bar = ?`.

I want to do this, to be able to update different values in a database with the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the keys and values and construct the SQL dynamically.

```
app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  let whitelist = ["foo", "bar"];
  let checkWhitelist = Object.keys(req.body).filter((e) => whitelist.includes(e)).length > 0;
  if (checkWhitelist) {
    let assign = Object.keys(req.body).map(k => `\`${k}\` = ?`).join(', ');
    let vals = Object.values(req.body);
    const sql = `UPDATE users SET ${assign}`;
    connection.query(sql, vals, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({err: err});
      } else {
        res.send({updated: true});
      }
    })
  } else {
    res.send({err: "Error"});
  }
});
```

Note that this is dangerous, since you're trusting the client to send valid column names. In real life you should white-list the column names.

Comment: One should also use back-ticks around the column names, even if they pass an allow-list.

Comment: Your approach is working. But I don't want to have insecure code. Thus do I need to check if the keys are part of a given array? @BillKarwin with back-ticks you mean ``\`${k}\`  = ?``?

Comment: Yes, because even if you verify the column name against an array (which I do recommend), what if you have a legit column that conflicts with a SQL reserved keyword, or which contains whitespace or punctuation characters? Those are legal identifiers in SQL, but you need to delimit them.